# Signficant Chi square despite no difference in variable

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test

I am comparing the complications of 2 treatment groups (different sample size:37 and 7), with no events in the variable ( No strokes in either treatment group) yet the Chi square test is giving me a p value of <0.01?

Comment: The size of the smaller group seems too low. Chi-square test requires that the expected frequency in each cell be >= 5.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way I can compare the variable in the 2 groups? Would it be suitable to use percentages in the chi square test rather than absolute figures?

Comment: Run a randomized test.

Comment: I am sorry, but what is a randomised test?

Comment: The following Wikipedia page describes the nonparametric options available to you. It does so relatively concisely:    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(statistics). 
   In particular, randomized tests are explained in the middle of the page.

Comment: Thank you. I have read the permutation tests. I had already tried fisher exact test and no p value could be deducted. I presume this is because the mean is 0 and dividing by 0 gives infinity (with my limited knowledge). Do you have any other suggestions? I thought of just assuming non-significance based on common sense.

Comment: Do randomized tests and bootstrap. The p-value always exists. I can only advise you on the methodological aspects. Unfortunately, my time constrains do not allow for rolling up my sleeves and interpreting the results of every user... Please do what I suggested and you will arrive at a relatively accurate verdict.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly follow @Stans's advice and do a permutation/randomization test.

Another alternative is to test the proportions. Agresti and Coull wrote a seminal article on this in *The American Statistician* in 1998. They propose a simple method of adding 2 "successes" and two "failures" and also some more sophisticated methods that are available in R and SAS and probably other packages.

The simple method would, in your case, mean that instead of testing 0/37 vs. 0/7 you would test 2/39 vs. 2/9.